# How to run java code in HTML

Tags: java, html

I have a piece of java code I would like to run in my web browser and publish online.  How can I do this without using applets?  I have tried java vertx but I am not sure how to use it and there are no good tutorials online.

Comment: I think google has some kind of converter you can feed with java and get javascript EDIT: They actually have that. http://www.gwtproject.org/overview.html

Comment: @Distjubo: The Google Web Toolkit (GWT). Much more than a converter, more an entire framework for client- and server-side code, all in Java, which auto-generates whatever JavaScript it needs.

Comment: @Bibby There you have it. Use it.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you can't. Browsers don't "speak" Java natively, which is why applets required a plugin. As you probably know, Google is in the process of removing support for the plugin technology used by the Java plugin (NPAPI) and so soon Java won't work in Chrome at all (it already doesn't under Linux).

Your only real options are:

1. Provide a means of running it server-side, like http://ideone.com and various other "online" compilers do.
2. Translate it from Java to JavaScript (either manually or using a tool), which the browser can then run. But note that Java and JavaScript are not only markedly different languages despite a superficial similarity in syntax, but the standard environment for each is also quite different from the other.

How you do either of those is much too broad a question for SO.